# Create RPM package with runtime libraries and executable file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have created a C++ application under redhat linux environment. Beside this application, I have also created many *.so libraries required by the application. The created application uses some Boost C++ libraries, e.g. -lboost_system, -lboost_thread and etc

I wish to deploy this application and its required runtime libraries onto the production machine without exposing/recompiling the source codes and without having Boost C++ full installation on the production machine. Is it possible?

The application directories structure in development machine as follows:

```
~/SysA/debug/main/main     (executable binary file)
~/SysA/debug/main/config   (configuration text file)
~/SysA/debug/lib1/libA.so
~/SysA/debug/lib2/libB.so
~/SysA/debug/lib3/libC.so
   :
   :
```

I have attempted to make my first following RPM SPEC file as follows, but stucked:

```
Name: SYSTEM
Version: 0.1
Release: 1.0
BuildRoot: %{_topdir}BUILD/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}

AutoReqProv: no

%description
System testing

%prep
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%clean
rm -rf %RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(644, root, root)
%changelog
```

Wish someone can help me out...

Answer (score 0):

You should either create a 2nd RPM for Boost libraries (to be installed together with your RPM) or link Boost libraries statically into your application.